# Importing txt files in Access using VBA - date format issue - import specification

Tags: ms-access, import, vba

I'm importing txt files which have been exported from Excel and end up in a general format i.e. 42408 etc.

When importing it into Access, I don't have a problem doing it as a import. (I set data type to Date etc. and it works -> no import errors.)

However, when I try to **multi-import** using the code below, everything imports EXCEPT the date for which I get a **"Type conversion error"**.

Now, I believe the issue is with the **import specification**. [SEE IMAGE]

Does anybody know a configuration for the import specification that would make it work?

**[Database file here (also I have included the import txt file)](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=13131211192666956596)**

[image]

```
Sub import_multiple_files()
On Error GoTo bImportFiles_Click_Err

Dim objFS As Object, objFolder As Object
Dim objFiles As Object, objF1 As Object
Dim strFolderPath As String

strFolderPath = "s:\downloads\import_files\"
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strFolderPath)
Set objFiles = objFolder.files

For Each objF1 In objFiles
    If Right(objF1.Name, 3) = "txt" Then
        DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "TextImportSpecs", "tblImportedFiles", strFolderPath & objF1.Name, False
        Name strFolderPath & objF1.Name As "s:\downloads\Archived Files\" & objF1.Name 'Move the files to the archive folder
    End If
Next

Set objF1 = Nothing
Set objFiles = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFS = Nothing

bImportFiles_Click_Exit:
Exit Sub

bImportFiles_Click_Err:
MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
Resume bImportFiles_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't ever use strings if it can be avoided.

42408 is just the numeric value of the date value. You can easily convert this to data type Date with CDate:

```
 RealDate: CDate(NumericDate)

 42408 -> 2016-02-08
```

To avoid a later update and/or field, don't import the file but link it. Then create a query that reads the linked table and performs any conversion needed.

Now use this query as source for your import or further processing.

Comment: yh this would work but the problem is I dont want to add any extra fields. If I could get the import specification configured to work, that would be the best solution.

Comment: Alternatively, OP can import to a temp table and migrate with append queries to final table with any needed conversion/calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually import the table with date column as date and save the import and call from code as DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "Your import name"

Comment: this wont however do what i intend which is to input ALL files (txt files) regardless of the amount of files or the name from a specific folder

Comment: My bad. This is the work around I use. Import date as strings. Later add a column as datetime  and update the new column DoCmd.RunSQL "update Tablename"
" set [Start_date] = datevalue(startdate)"